# python how to decode words using stack?

Tags: python

i have a txt file which is written like this:

```
6
abcd<<<<<<
n<J<g<1<A<
ABCD<<<1>>>2<<3>->>>>>>
```

and i want to decode this file by python using 'stack' .
at this file, '<' means cursor moves this ← way
'>'means cursor moves → this way
and '-' means delete the left word right after cursor's location.

so finally, what i should want is

```
abcd
A1gJn
A1BC32
```

i tried to make a certain function to solve this question
but i don't know what is wrong with my function.
The written below is what i made.

```
def decodeString_stack(string):
"""Recover a string from a keylog string
input: string(string), output:(decoded string)
deCoded[ ] : list of decoded string(cursor left)
temp[ ] : list of decoded string(cursor right)
"""
    deCoded=[]; temp=[]

  for ch in string:
     if ch=='<':
        x=deCoded.pop()
        temp.append(x)
     elif ch=='>':
        x=temp.pop()
        deCoded.append(x)
     elif ch=='-':
        del deCoded[len(deCoded)-1]
  return ''.join(deCoded)
```

it always stops because list is empty one

```
import time
fr=open("input.txt",'r')
fw=open("output_txt",'w')

print('start decoding')
startTime=time.time()

for aLine in fr:
   deCoded=decodeString_stack(aLine)
   print(deCoded)

exeTime=time.time()-startTime

print("decode complete(laspe time= %.2f sec)" %exeTime)
fr.close(); fw.close()
```

how can i make it right?

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you are defining an empty list, 'deCoded', then immediately trying to 'pop()' from it. For pop to work, something has to be in the list. I suspect this is homework so I won't delve too far into a solution - just note that pop is taking something off the stack, but you can't take something off if nothing exists : )

```
    deCoded=[]; temp=[]

  for ch in string:
     if ch=='<':
        x=deCoded.pop()
        temp.append(x)
```

Without giving away too much, hopefully this will get you started. Also, if you don't use it already, I highly recommend Pycharm. You can get it free - and it will allow you to step debug through your code. It will be a life saver.

```
def decode_line(line : str):
    temp = []
    decoded = []
    for char in line:
        if char == "<":
            if temp:
                c = temp.pop()
                decoded.append(c)
        elif char == ">":
            pass
        elif char == "-":
            pass
        else:
            temp.append(char)

    reversed = decoded[::-1]
    return reversed


with open('source.txt') as source:
    for line in source:
        out = decode_line(line)
        print(out)
```

Comment: can you just give me a hint about making 'deCoded' into  not-emptied state? i have no idea how to determine deCoded and temp

Comment: @user50127; Give me a sec and I'll whip something up.